# Why do unresolved dependencies appear while migrating from 2.2.1 to 2.3.1?

Tags: playframework, sbt

Hello I have tried to migrate my play project to newer version and I have generated some errors which I couldnt repair. I was trying to do it like it was shown at play framework site migrate from play 2.2.x to play 2.3.x

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play- 
java-jdbc_2.11;2.3.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java-ebean_2.11;2.3.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.11;2.3.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-mailer_2.11;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-util_2.11;2.2.0: not found
[error] Total time: 31 s, completed 2014-09-17 18:21:00
1. Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
```

My build.sbt looks like:

```
name := "error"

version := "0.1.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

doc in Compile <<= target.map(_ / "none")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.24"
libraryDependencies += "org.fusesource.scalate" % "scalate-core" % "1.5.3"
libraryDependencies += "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-util" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.thrift" % "libthrift" % "0.9.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-core-asl" % "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.3.1"
```

I will be very thankful for every help cause I couldn't find resolution for this anywhere.

In older version play 2.2.2 I had in build.sbt also at the end
play.Project.playJavaSettings
and all was working perfectly when I was trying to run play with this last play.Project.playJavaSettings it gave error at starting running

```
/home/error/workspace/play-angular/build.sbt:35: error: object Project is not a   
member of package play
play.Project.playJavaSettings
     ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Comment: I think you may need to add:

    `lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)`

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with `project/plugins.sbt` in which you missed the Typesafe Releases repository (resolver). Add the following and start over.

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

There's also the shortcut available (if you want to go *geeky*):

```
resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")
```